# File not found issue in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?
header("Content-type: octet/stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=a.mp3");
readfile("http://adstorage.jamba.net/storage/view/325/0/fa/Fairytale.mp3");
?>
```

This code is working great in my `localhost` but displays `File not found` when uploaded to my server

Comment: You have uploaded `Fairytale.mp3` to `/storage/view/325/0/fa` ?

Comment: Then check for file permissions

Comment: else it wouldn't work in localhost too

Comment: i have uploaded this php file in another website.

Comment: i don't belong to `adstorage.jamba.net`

Comment: Could it be the short open tags? check the source of the remote page and if you see the php code add `<?php` as the opening tag

Comment: Security on the hosting preventing outbound connections?

Comment: When you say file not found.. do you mean the uploaded *.php is not found or the remote file?

Comment: Can you please confirm whether the error is a 404 page from your site, or a PHP script error? If the latter, please post the full error message.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have PHP permissions to read external files?

These permissions might be different on your local machine and the web server.

According to the [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) documentation:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

Comment: why would these permissions result in a 404? they'd just result in php errors, surely.

Comment: The OP states that he got a '*file not found issue*', not a 404 HTTP response... You came with that one :)

Comment: Fair point, although he does say the screen displays 'File not found'. PHP protocol wrapper errors would be 'failed to open stream', 'Operation not permitted', etc..

Comment: Yes, that point is a bit unclear. The OP did not specify the exact error message (including line number if it is indeed a PHP error) or details about which mechanism (PHP, HTTP, ...) threw the error

Answer (score 0):

**Please set the file permission so only it can be working correctly.. **

Comment: you checked the comment discussion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code you've posted has anything to do with the 404. A code error with your mp3 download would not produce a 404.

Chances are your CodeIgniter setup is wrong/different on your remote host. Check the routing is working. Do other controllers work?